# setting value of dijit/form/numbertextbox sets displayedValue -- not value

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I'm setting the value of a dijit/form/NumberTextBox programatically and when I debug I see that the displayedValue has been set, not the value.  Any idea why it would behave this way?  My NumberTextBox is located on a template widget, maybe that has something to do with it?

Template:

```
<input type="text"
               style="width: 50px; height:20px;"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberTextBox"
    required="true" 
    data-dojo-attach-point="tbDiam"
    data-dojo-props="constraints:{min:6,max:100,places:0},
    invalidMessage:'Please enter numeric value, no decimals.',
    rangeMessage:'Invalid diameter.' ""/>
```

Setting the value:

```
this.tbDiam.set("value", "25");
```

getting the value:

```
this.tbDiam.value; //undefined
this.tbDiam.displayedValue();//"25"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a dojo form widget can be retrieved by using `get("value")`. The reason why the `.value` does not work is that tbDiam is just a wrapper for the actual input and doesn't actually hold the value of the input. So `tbDiam.get("value")` should return what you want.